# Estimating Riemann Inegrals

Tags: riemann-integration

Let R be the rectangle given by 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, and let f(x, y) =
x + 5y. We want to estimate the integral
∬f(x, y) dx dy.

a. Divide each side of the rectangle into three equal parts, and for each
of the nine squares pick the sample point in the lower left hand corner.
Compute the Riemann sum.

b. Use the same subdivision, but now pick your sample points on the
upper right of each square. Compute the Riemann sum.

c. How good an estimate for the integral does this give?

Comment: Nice...and what have you done so far besides ordering us to do what *you* must do? Any ideas, efforts, insights...?

Comment: Generally best if you give us what you have done and what you are struggling with.